# heroku and nodejs erorr (Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch)

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, discord, discord.js

I am using discord.js and I have a code where if someone votes for my bot on https://top.gg the bot will send a message, but it got this error

```
Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
```

Here is my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const DBL = require('dblapi.js');
const dbl = new DBL(process.env.DBTOKEN, { webhookPort: 5000, webhookAuth: 'password' }, bot)
dbl.webhook.on('ready', hook => {
    console.log(`Webhook running at http://${hook.hostname}:${hook.port}${hook.path}`);
  });

dbl.webhook.on('vote', vote => {
  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('A user just upvoted!')
  .setDescription(`Thank you **${vote.user.tag}** for voting me!`)
  .setColor('FF000')
  .setThumbnail(vote.user.displayAvatarURL())
  let votechannel = bot.channels.cache.find(x => x.id === '775360008786280468')
  votechannel.send(embed)
})
```

Please help me that would be very appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku changes the Port that runs Node Application from time to time. Try changing your webhook port to `process.env.PORT`. Check the code below.

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const bot = new Discord.Client();

const DBL = require('dblapi.js');
const dbl = new DBL(process.env.DBTOKEN, { webhookPort: process.env.PORT || 5000, webhookAuth: 'password' }, bot)
dbl.webhook.on('ready', hook => {
    console.log(`Webhook running at http://${hook.hostname}:${hook.port}${hook.path}`);
  });

dbl.webhook.on('vote', vote => {
  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('A user just upvoted!')
  .setDescription(`Thank you **${vote.user.tag}** for voting me!`)
  .setColor('FF000')
  .setThumbnail(vote.user.displayAvatarURL())
  let votechannel = bot.channels.cache.find(x => x.id === '775360008786280468')
  votechannel.send(embed)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Heroku actually tells you which port you're supposed to bind your web server to through the `PORT` environment variable, which you can access at `process.env.PORT` on node.

Change your `webhookPort` from `5000` to that variable and it should work :)